# Sending data to PHP web service using Objective-C and getting data back

Tags: php, objective-c, json

Before I wanted to send data to the web service, I would get back valid JSON objects. However, now that I've added in some authentication I do not get any JSON objects back when I call it from my iOS app, but if I enter the URL with the applicable $_GET parameters in my browser I successfully get JSON back - which makes no sense to me.

I've looked around at the similar questions asked here and none of them worked, they'd all crash my app with the error "Returned NULL data", so I figured I'd ask here and see what stupid thing I was doing wrong.

Here's the objective-C bit:

```
//Make the string and URL

NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/~Danny.Martin/Services/sites/getInfo.php?email=%@&password=%@", _username.text, _password.text];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

//TESTING - What URL are we using?
NSLog(@"%@", urlString);


//Take the data we get back and convert it into JSON
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSMutableDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

The URL I get back is(edited since it won't let me do the localhost thing):

```
/~Danny.Martin/Services/sites/getInfo.php?email=Danny&password=password
```

Which is correct, and when I enter it into my browser I get the correct JSON back. If I change the username or password parameters, then I get nothing back.

Comment: Is the password really "password", because you aren't doing any url encoding and that could cause URLWithString: to return nil.

Comment: As Sam said, you should not be using `GET` request for authentication (because password is easily intercepted). You really want `POST` (with the presumption that your production server will support HTTPS), at the very least. Furthermore, when doing `GET` (or `POST` with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) you probably want to use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` in case your password had any reserved characters in it. Also, `localhost` won't work unless you're doing that in the simulator (assuming web server is running on your Mac).

Comment: Having said all that, without sharing relevant portions of server code, we can't tell you why it's not working.